# How can I replicate this pattern in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, cc-2014

I'm trying to replicate the background pattern of this image in Illustrator CC but am not having much success. I tried the star tool, but it didn't look right.

[image]

**Updated**
When I select all the lines and click divide on the pathfinder panel, they disappear. See below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to select both lines and rectangle. Please read very carefuly my short tutorial. Every word is important. I've written: "Then select all objects and click on the Divide tool".
Basicly you are telling Illustrator to divide the rectangle bellow according to your lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not that hard. And here is how you can make it:

**1.** Create a desired size rectangle, add a line across it and align them properly to center. Then copy-rotate the line by 10 degrees (or 6, 360 needs to be divisible without remainder).
[image: Creating rectangle with line and start rotating with duplicate]

**2.** Then select all objects and click on the Divide tool on the Pathfinder Panel.
[image: Selecting objects and dividing them]

**3.** Now easily select every secont object and and color it in any colors you like.
[image: Selecting objects for coloring]

**4.** Add the circle element across the whole rectangle and apply the fading-out gradient as shown on picture.
[image: Adding circle element with fading gradient]

**5.** Add black star element with similar properties as shown.
[image: Adding black star element]
Here is how it should look like.

[image: Black star element added]

**6.** Now add white triangle element and voilà - you are finished.
[image]

(Sorry for long post , but that was the only way to show)

Comment: If I could upvote twice I would. Thanks for taking the time to create this very detailed answer!

Comment: I've posted an update, I am having issues with one of your steps. Thanks

Comment: My bad, I was only selecting the lines, not the rectangle. Mind blanked on what divide does. Thanks !!