# Is there a name for this striped dual color background?

Tags: background, style-identification

**Related Question:** [How can I replicate this pattern in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/43002/how-can-i-replicate-this-pattern-in-illustrator)

Look at the background of this image, the dual-color one.

[image: http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2014/231/f/8/lupi__by_im0ren-d7vsr4f.jpg]

What is this kind of background called and how can I recreate it?

Comment: Hi spyk3iartist. Over the last couple days, you have asked multiple questions about similarly styled images and how to reproduce them. As we are not a request-a-tutorial website, please consider googling for tutorials on the specific style. There's bound to be thousands of hits on 'manga style Illustrator tutorial' or 'Photoshop animation style tutorial', or 'starburst style background tutorial' for this specific question. If you are stuck on certain *parts* of the process, be welcome to post those questions here. As-is, these questions are way too broad for our Q&A format. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called 'starburst' backgrounds, and we have a nice answer about them [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/43002/how-can-i-replicate-this-pattern-in-illustrator).